# How to wait for user's input in windows form while executing an event

Tags: c#-4.0

How can we make a windows form application's event wait for user input?

Like if I ordered my pc to shutdown or log off or hibernate or sleep, it then confirms me that I really wants to shutdown/log off or hibernate or sleep if I say that yes perform action then it performs otherwise, if I deny or say abort it will then abort that operation.
But not just directly shutdown pc after it got command w/o confirming.

I'm using it in speech recognition computer over voice command system I don't want a message box to appear and ask me to yes or no i made it speak and ask me question whether I want to do it or not but it's not waiting for my answer.

Current code:

```
string speech = e.Result.Text.ToString();
```

string[] terminateFind = speech.Split(' ');

```
        if (terminateFind[0]=="Terminate"||terminateFind[0]=="Kill")
        {
            speech = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < terminateFind.Length-1; i++)
            {
                speech += terminateFind[i]+" ";
            }
            KillingProcess = Int32.Parse(terminateFind[terminateFind.Length-1]);
        }
switch (speech) {
case "Terminate Process Number ":
case "Kill Process Number ":
case "Close Process Number ":

    string Procr = listBox1.Items[KillingProcess - 1].ToString();
    string[]Kilproc = Procr.Split('-');
    int Pid = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcName[KillingProcess - 1])[0].Id;
    Travis.Speak("Terminating Porcess named : " + Kilproc[Kilproc.Length - 1]);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    //     sRecog.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sRecog_SpeechRecognized);


    if (e.Result.Text.ToString() == "Abort") {
    AbortTheComand = true;
    }
    if (AbortTheComand == false) {

    Process.GetProcessById(Pid, ".").Kill();
    } else {
    Travis.Speak("Operation Terminated by user : ");
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your codes? Did you start coding yet ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i have edited post with code check it out again please :P

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

First of all the important thing,*you are supposed to post the code that you've tried along with your question*.

I assume you have an `Action Button` in your `Form`,whose `Click Event` is responsible to handle all the stuff you mentioned.

```
private void Action_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some Code...

    //Decide whether to Shutdown.
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to shutdown Windows ?", "App Name", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //Logic to Shutdown Windows.
    }
    else if (dr == DialogResult.No)
    {
        //React accordingly or do what you want.
    }

    //Some Code...
}
```

The same code can be used to decide Hibernate,Sleep or Log off events as well.